# text box with unselectable ='on' getting selected in ie on tab press from previous text field

Tags: button, input, tabs, focus, selected

`textbox` with `unselectable ='on'` getting selected in ie for tab press from previous text field.

form 'input1' on tab press it should go to 'input3' with out selecting input2.

```
< input name="input1" type="text" value="input1"  / >
< input name="input2" type="text" value="input2" unselectable="on" />
< input name="input3" type="text"  />
< button>clickme< /button>
```

I tried like below,

```
$("input[unselectable]").focus(function(){
            $(this).blur();
        });
$(input[unselectable]).focus(function(){
        $(this).next('input').focus();
     });
```

But it is not working ie.

the another case here is if 'input3' is also `unselectable="on"` on press tab from 'input1' it should go to button/anchor ect..

solution either in `javascript` or `jquery` or any other idea..

Answer (score 1):

Just defind tabindex = -1  in

```
< input name="input2" type="text" value="input2" unselectable="on" tabindex = -1 />
```